# Problema con tabla intermedia y relación muchos a muchos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy aprendiendo a programar y acá tengo un problema a la hora de llenar los datos una tabla intermedia. La página que estoy intentando es hacer sobre Gestión de proyectos.
Tengo una tabla llamada usuarios cuya clave primaria es el DNI, una tabla llamada proyectos donde la clave primaria es idproyecto y, como varios usuarios pueden estar en un mismo proyecto y un usuario puede tener varios proyectos, se forma una relacion de muchos a muchos y por ende una tabla intermediaria cuyas fk son las dos pk de las otras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que quiero hacer que al añadir un proyecto nuevo, se autocomplete también la tabla intermedia usuariosproyectos con el respectivo DNI del usuario que esta agregando el proyecto y el id del proyecto que esta siendo agregado y no sé como hacer la sentencia. Por si es necesario, también digo que estoy usando php, mysql, fetch, js, pdo y mvc. Y la sentencia que uso en el modelo a la hora de agregar el proyecto es esta `$sql = "INSERT INTO proyectos (nombre) VALUES (?)";`

Pongo las modelo, el contolador, el jsy el html de la clase proyecto
Este es el modelo

```
<?php
include_once'conexion.php';
include_once'validar.php';

class Proyecto{
    protected $idproyecto;
    protected $nombre;

    protected function registrarProyecto(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO proyectos (nombre) VALUES (?)";
        $conexion = Conexion::conectar();
        $resultado=$conexion->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->bindParam(1, $this->nombre);
        $resultado->execute();          
    }
    
}
?>
```

Este es el controlador

```
<?php
require '../modelo/proyecto.php';
include'../modelo/validar.php';
class ProyectoC extends Proyecto{
    public function SaveProyectoForModel ($nombre){
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
        $this->registrarProyecto();
    }
}   
    if(isset($_POST['proyecto'])){
        $instaciacontrolador = new ProyectoC();
        $instaciacontrolador->SaveProyectoForModel(
            $_POST['proyecto']      
        );
    }

?>
```

Este es el Js

```js
eventListeners();

// Variable global
var listProyectos = document.querySelector('ul#projects');

// Agrego una funcion para cada boton. Primero el de agregar proyecto, segundo el de agregar una tarea y por ultimo, las acciones de las tareas.

function eventListeners() {
    
    document.querySelector('.crearProyecto').addEventListener('click', newProject);
}

// Esta función crea el input (cuadro de texto) para sumar el nuevo proyecto  captura el valor valor para enviarlo a la base de datos a tra ves de "DBsaveProject".

function newProject(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var listProyectos = document.querySelector('ul#projects');

    var newProject = document.createElement('li');
    newProject.innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="newProject">`;
    listProyectos.appendChild(newProject);
    
    var inputnewProject = document.querySelector('#newProject');
    
    
    inputnewProject.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
        var enter = e.which || e.keyCode;
        
        if(enter === 13) {
            DBsaveProject(inputnewProject.value);
            listProyectos.removeChild(newProject);
        }
    });
}

// Esta función guarda el proyecto en la base de datos

function DBsaveProject(nombreProyecto) {
    // A partir de aca se crea el llamado a Ajax.

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('proyecto', nombreProyecto);

    fetch('controlador/proyectoc.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
     })
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    
}
```

Este es el html

```html
<aside class="contenedorProyectos">
    <div class="panel crearProyecto">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Nuevo Proyecto <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> </a>

    </div>

    <div class="panel listProyectos">
        <h2>Proyectos</h2>
        <ul id="projects">

                        <li>

                        </li>

        </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: estas haciendo las consultas con php? podrias mostrar tu script para tener una mejor vision y asi poder ayudarte

Comment: Si te refieres a que no sabes hacer un `$sql = "INSERT INTO usuariosproyectos (DNI, idproyecto) VALUES (?, ?)";` entonces mejor que repases como se hacen consultas **básicas** en SQL conjuntamente con PHP usando mysqli o PDO (no se cual de ambos es el que usas).

Comment: Several Tool y Masterguru gracias por responder. Ahi añadi el codigo. Y quiza no me exprese bien pero la sentencia funciona perfectamente lo que yo necesito ahora es una forma de tomar el id del ultimo proyecto agregado y el dni del usuario que lo agrego e insertarlos en la tabla intermedia. Y me gustaria que se haga en el momento que el usuario agrega su proyecto, no se si me explico.

Comment: Ahi agregue las partes del codigo, disculpen soy nuevo y pense que se habia guardado jaja

Answer (score 0):

Como lo entiendo debes primero insertar el proyecto en la base de datos, luego de alguna manera debes obtener el id con el que se guardó el proyecto y por último debes insertar el id del usuario y del proyecto en la tabla usuariosproyectos. En pocas palabras tendrás que hacer 2 inserts.

Comment: Claro, mi tema es como. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).